# Use the law of logarithms to expand an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\log\sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { x+2 }{ x^{ 4 }(x^{ 2 }+4) }  } $$

How is this answer incorrect?

$$\frac { 1 }{ 3 } [\log(x+2)-(4\log x+\log(x^ 2+4))]$$

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: The answer key saids otherwise.

Comment: What did the answer key say?

Comment: $$\frac { 1 }{ 3 } [log(x+2)-4logx-log(x^{ 2 }+4)]$$

Comment: If $x=-1$, or thereabouts, there is an issue.

Comment: That's the same thing. They just distributed the $-$ sign over $4 \log x + \log(x^2+4)$.

Comment: It's very hard to see how the text books answer is the same thing once combined...

Comment: with this simplify you have to know that your domain will be changed and that is not exactly with your initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your answer though the person asking the question might be expecting it to be expanded into $$\tfrac { 1 }{ 3 } \log(x+2)-\tfrac43\log x-\tfrac13\log(x^ 2+4)$$ to remove many of the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

with this simplify you have to know that your domain will be changed and that is not exactly with your initial question.suppose you want to simplify

[image]

this you can't input negative integer in this,but if you simplify that:

[image]

that you can input negative numbers,so domain changed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can't put negative numbers into $\log(x)$ either.

Comment: A better answer would be that $\log(x^4)$ does not have the same domain as $4\log(x)$: consider $x\lt 0$.  This affects this question for $-2 \lt x \lt 0$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, with reservation about function domain. $Dom(log\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+2}{x^{4}(x^{2}+4)}})=\left(-2,\infty\right)/\{0\}$ 
$$ Dom[\frac{1}{3}(log(x+2)-(4log(x)+log(x^{2}+4)]=(0,\infty)$$
For example, if $x=-1$, original function give $-log(5)/3$, but your formula "Error"